# How to completely empty an Ethereum wallet using W3.py

Tags: web3.py, ethereumj

I have an ethereum wallet, I need to calculate the amount to completely empty the wallet.

So currently i calculate the needed gas like this,

```
needed_gas = w3.eth.gasprice * 210000

amount_to_send = balance - needed_gas
```

However, the are still few cents remaining in the account, this causes a loop as I try to transfer untill the amount_to_send value is 0.

Comment: Change `210000` to `21000`.

Comment: I tried this, now I get an out of gas error.
The amount in my wallet was 0.65245773
After using the above the logic, I tried to transfer 0.065204958

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same